# Can't access tuple inside 2d array python

Tags: python, tuples, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array that looks much like this:

```
[[(0, 0), ('', 0), ('', 0), ('', 0), ('', 0), ('', 0)], [(0, 0), ('', 0), ('', 0), ('', 0), ('', 0), ('', 0)]]
```

I am trying to access the values of a tuple from a given cell like this:

```
x,y = self.cell_array[col][row]
```

It gives me this error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check your `col` and `row` values.

Comment: maybe your indices are string and not integers?

Comment: Can't you just _read_ the error message ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type of col and row must be type `int`

replace:

```
x,y = self.cell_array[col][row]
```

to:

```
x,y = self.cell_array[int(col)][int(row)]
```